# What is the Kitaev Model and why has it become so popular?

Tags: ising-model, spin-models

I am seeing Kitaev Model everywhere. It feels like the spin-glass model of our time. How the Kitaev model differ from spin-glass and why it can be used everywhere? Looking at equation 1 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01740) suggests it's basically a spin-glass model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01740) linked in the original post already answers some of the post's questions.

- *What is the Kitaev Model?*

It's a lattice model where

> nearest  neighbor spin degrees of freedom interact via a strongly anisotropic nearest-neighbor Ising exchange [...] The Kitaev interactions along neighboring bonds cannot be satisfied simultaneously, giving rise to ‘exchange frustration’ and driving the system into a Quantum spin liquid (QSL) phase.

- *Why it became so popular?*

> The Kitaev honeycomb model is arguably the paradigmatic example of QSL, because of its unique combination of being experimentally relevant, exactly solvable and hosting a variety of different interesting gapped and gapless QSL phases, not the least a chiral QSL that harbors nonabelian Ising anyons

- *How the Kitaev model differ from spin-glass?*

Spin glasses exhibit static, frozen ground states and meta-stable states, while in quantum spin liquids

> the spins fluctuate strongly even at zero temperature.

Or, as more explicitly put by Perreault in [his PhD. dissertation](https://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/185143),

> These two states are particularly distinguished by
>   their dynamics since a spin glass has a very long single-spin autocorrelation time while a spin-liquid lacks such frozen spin configurations.

One could then ask which characteristic of the model (or material) allows for QSL. According to Balents' [paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature08917) ([e-print](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/41895544_Spin_liquids_in_frustrated_magnets)) a possibility is systems where

> quantum effects are strong, and there are no obvious energy barriers [between low-temperature configurations].

- *Why it can be used everywhere?*

It probably can't, but it's analytically solvable, which is a rare beast, so people are gonna apply it whenever possible and try to squeeze as much as possible from it.

Comment: Is kitaev model a QMA complete (Quantum NP) like spin glass is NP hard?

Comment: @0x90 I don't know, but I'm not sure I'm following you, since the model is exactly solvable.

Comment: spin glass is solvable too. This is about how much time it takes to solve it

Comment: Then I can't answer that, sorry.